# Can't get Atom editor ide-java package to work on new Mac installation

Tags: java, atom-editor

I have recently been using the Atom editor with its ide-java package to do some Java development. It has worked well enough for me and I'd like to continue to use it.

I have just refreshed my Mac from scratch after having some repairs done on it that required erasing the disk. Since installing on this refreshed Mac, I am getting red error highlights on pretty much every line of code, including the first line of files which start with a comment. Most of the errors have a message something like this:

`The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files`

A Google search shows this error and some fixes within Eclipse projects, but I am not (directly) using Eclipse and I've had a hard time figuring out how to fix the problem in ide-java.

I've tried deleting the `.project` file and the `.settings` folder and allowed them to be auto-regenerated. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing the ide-java package. I've tried setting the package's Java Home to both a Java 8 and a Java 10 home folder. None of these have made a difference.

Can anyone offer any advice on how to troubleshoot and make this work as it has for me in the past?

Comment: Hi @Tim, did you ever manage to get this resolved? I'm having the same problem on Windows.

Comment: Nope - I am in the process of abandoning Atom altogether because of this problem. I simply can't make it work no matter what I do.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this - you can try to reset atom settings. 
For linux:

```
mv ~/.atom ~/.atom.bak
```

You will have to install packages again, but this helped me to fix the issue